# Issue with Rendering Checkboxes and Labels in Django Template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, deployment

I'm facing issues in my Django template while trying to create checkboxes for food options. I created a form titled cuisine_choices, and I am able to successfully loop through the selection of food from my template, but its not allowing me to properly display it.

When I use the following code:

`{% for food in cuisine.choices %} <input type="checkbox" name="food">{{ food }} {% endfor %}`

I encounter an unexpected behavior where I get the correct amount of checkboxes but with no label attached to it. However, when I write the code like this:

`{% for food in cuisine.choices %} <input type="checkbox" name={{ food }}> {% endfor %}`

I get the properly labeled checkboxes, except each label ends in ">. For example:
Mexican">  Chinese">  Italian">  Indian">  Japanese">  French">  Thai">  Mediterranean">  American">

While trying to figure out what was wrong I tried the following code:

`{% for food in cuisine.choices %} <input type="checkbox" name="Food">Test {% endfor %}`

And I got the correct amount of checkboxes, each labeled as "Test".

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how I can correctly render checkboxes with their labels in my template?